# Identifying values from one histogram into another

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have a program (a model about some population) that produces some data (what interests us: ranking and payoffs), with which I plot two histograms.

- **The data:**
  I write two lists, *rank* and *payoffs*, in which the i-th index represents the position in a ranking and how much has earned the i-th member of the population. E.g:

> ```
> rank    = [3, 6, 7, 15,..., 1, 2]
> payoffs = [334, 54, 123, 34,..., 12, 100]
> ```

- **The histograms:**
  I plot the lists rank and payoffs as histograms, and I get something like this:
  [image: Ranking] [image: Payoffs]
- **The problem:**
  I want to identify *IN THE PAYOFFS' HISTOGRAM* where are the members with the *HIGHEST RANKING*. I do not know how to get them, in order to plot them with different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am going to post the answer I came up with, in case someone wants to make something different; but I think it can be highly improved.*

First, you have some data, and for example, we take numpy's (np) random generator, do `ranks = [np.random.randint(0,10) for x in range(10)]`; and want I want to identify are the ones that correspond to the highest histogram's bin (as noted in the question, this is what I wanted), so:

`import matplolib.pyplot as plt
 histo = plt.hist(ranks)
 bins = histo[1]`

(I did this because of the way I coded before, so it was easier implementing in this way.) Here `bins` store the limits of the bins that matplotlib produced for the histogram.

Then,
`indexes_max = [i for i,x in enumerate(ranks) if x == max(bins)]`
will store the indexes of the data in the highest bin. Using `min` function will work for the lowest values.

Finally, I only have to get the data in a good way to plot it. Here, `payoffs_temp` was the list of the data for the "Payoffs histogram".

```
others = [payoffs_temp[i] for i in indexes_others]
maxs = [payoffs_temp[i] for i in indexes_max]
join = [others, maxs]
plt.hist(join, histtype='bar', stacked=True, label=['Rest', 'Max rank'])
plt.close()
```

So the whole code (for this) will look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ranks = [np.random.randint(0,10) for x in range(10)]
histo = plt.hist(ranks)
bins = histo[1]
indexes_max = [i for i,x in enumerate(ranks) if x == max(bins)]
others = [payoffs_temp[i] for i in indexes_others]
maxs = [payoffs_temp[i] for i in indexes_max]
join = [others, maxs]
plt.hist(join, histtype='bar', stacked=True, label=['Rest', 'Max rank'])
plt.close()
```

Hope it helps someone.